# difference between p-automorphism and automorphism of order p

Tags: group-theory

Is there difference between p-automorphism and automorphism of order p?

I looked up in internet some time they say they are same but some time it's look like there is a different between them 
for example in some paper I read
"It is a sufficient condition to have a non-inner p-automorphism (not necessarily of order p)"
I am confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A $p$-automorphism (or more generally a $p$-element of a group) is one whose order is a *power* of $p$.